# Deny Wordpress Search System on nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to write a rule to `nginx.conf` about deny the Wordpress search url. Because, we take DDOS attacks on search system.

URL structure is : `/?s=xxx`

I want to block (deny) all request on nginx firstly, after i will need to limit http requests (`limit_req_zone` feature) on this query via nginx.

Examples of flood queries:

```
75.213.48.178 - - [30/May/2015:14:45:09 +0300] "GET /?s=Xndxx HTTP/1.1" 200 4507 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 6812.88.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.153 Safari/537.36"
200.165.97.17 - - [30/May/2015:14:47:16 +0300] "GET /?s=dKKgtm HTTP/1.1" 200 4509 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36"
112.72.11.67 - - [30/May/2015:14:47:22 +0300] "GET /?s=CbjwC HTTP/1.1" 200 4508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
190.30.56.193 - - [30/May/2015:14:49:15 +0300] "GET /?s=xBMaS HTTP/1.1" 200 4508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
190.30.36.138 - - [30/May/2015:14:49:15 +0300] "GET /?s=RMZJhu HTTP/1.1" 200 4511 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
190.139.78.46 - - [30/May/2015:14:49:17 +0300] "GET /?s=FjNaKg HTTP/1.1" 200 4508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
181.10.91.198 - - [30/May/2015:14:49:23 +0300] "GET /?s=HTqvnT HTTP/1.1" 200 4510 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
186.153.232.128 - - [30/May/2015:14:49:23 +0300] "GET /?s=WPFYXI HTTP/1.1" 200 4510 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
181.110.55.62 - - [30/May/2015:14:50:23 +0300] "GET /?s=VnHfXU HTTP/1.1" 200 4510 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to match? did you try something? update your question with expected results..

Comment: How can i block basically all /?s=xxxxx get queries on nginx ?  ( btw i tried this url http://gadelkareem.com/2015/01/18/limiting-connections-requests-wordpress-nginx/ )